# How to navigate between Stack navigators Reactnative v5

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In my App stack i have the following code:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const FStack = ({navigation}) => (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Doc Types"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ header :() => null}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="P"
        component={PScreen}
      />
       <Stack.Screen
        name="W"
        component={WScreen}
      />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );

const LStack = ({navigation}) => (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
        name="L"
        component={LScreen}
        options={{ header :() => null}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="X"
        component={XScreen}
        options={{ header :() => null}}
      />

  
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
```

When I try to run `navigation.navigate('X');` from a screen in `Fstack` to the XScreen in the `LStack` it returns an error claiming I have no screen with the name XScreen.

Is there a way to solve this or do I have to put the `XScreen` in the Fstack as well.

Comment: Why you seperate the FStack and LStack? Put them together and they will work.

Comment: @ThanhChương It's because the Lstack has on onboarding page and when a bottom tab is hit it kept taking me t o a page on the Fstack. Separating them avoided this issue